# Unexpected behavior in jest.spyOn

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

I'm currently working with a combination of jest ts-jest with esm enabled,
I wrote my first set of tests for `index.test.ts` and everything went as expected:

```js
describe("Create logger", () => {
    let stdOutSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
    let log = "";

    beforeEach(() => {
        stdOutSpy = jest
            .spyOn(process.stdout, "write")
            .mockImplementation((value) => {
                log = value as string;
                return true;
            });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        process.env = {};
        stdOutSpy.mockReset();
        log = "";
    });

    describe("Log levels", () => {
        it("should use error level as default level", () => {
            const logger = createLogger({ label: "test" });
            logger.error("Error log");
            logger.warn("Warn log");
            expect(stdOutSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(log).toContain("Error");
        });

        it("should take LOGGER_INFO as the logger level when specific level not defined", () => {
            process.env.LOGGER_LEVEL = "warn";
            const logger = createLogger({ label: "test" });
            logger.warn("Warn log");
            logger.info("Info log");
            expect(stdOutSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
            expect(log).toContain("Warn");
        });
```

```
 PASS  tests/index.test.ts
  Create logger
    Log levels
      ✓ should use error level as default level (5 ms)
      ✓ should take LOGGER_INFO as the logger level when specific level not defined
      ✓ should use specific logger level when defined (1 ms)
    Transports
      ✓ should log as json in production (1 ms)
      ✓ should print with pretty output when using in development
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.722 s, estimated 1 s
```

However, WITHOUT making any changes to index.test.ts, I added a new file, `http-request-logger.test.ts` with a very simple test case:

```js
it("should work", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

After running the test, I notice that the only case passing is the `http-request-logger.test.ts`:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       5 failed, 1 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.714 s, estimated 1 s
```

It is also printing with console log, even when it should not due to the mock to the `process.stdout.write` mock

> [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/SebSV-GitHub/logger)

[image: Console logging]

> Note: If I change the name of the file removing the `.test` part from the `http-request-logger.test.ts` everything works back again.

Comment: You call your method twice `logger.error("Error log");
            logger.warn("Warn log");`

Comment: @droebi That is what I'm testing, that the logger only uses the correct level assigned

Comment: `Expected number of calls: 1`
`Received number of calls: 2` When you call it twice then you're expected no. is incorrect

Comment: Read the question carefully. The test works until I add a new file. There is no error with the implementation. In the code, the logger is executed twice but only prints once because the logger level blocks the second print.